# How to include D code in R package akin to C++

Tags: r, d

I know augmenting R with procedures written in D is not officially supported. But still, it should be possible, since D is mostly binary-compatible with C/C++. How to properly do that?

Are there already existing R packages or projects that merge D code with R?

Comment: Why down vote??? Which rule did I break?

Comment: An example of embedding D in python: https://github.com/ariovistus/pyd that you can extrapolate and follow this idiom: https://github.com/asieira/SnakeCharmR to make it possible to create this unholy alliance of code.

Comment: Adam, I think SO guys wanted to see you actually trying to find the solution by yourself. So you have to tell them what did you try to do... "Where can I find..." questions typically get downvoted and closed...

Answer (score 2):

First, you'll have to [write a D library with a C interface](https://dlang.org/dll-linux.html). For convenience's sake, create a shared library as shown in [Dynamically Loading a D DLL From a C Program](https://dlang.org/dll-linux.html#dso9).

After creating the library, you'll have to load it in R. I don't know the language, but a quick search suggests using `dyn.load` and `.Call`. This will impose the limitations of C, but maybe someone has a better idea.